# How to prevent ReSharper to search in compiled libraries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, resharper

I use ReSharper 7.1.1 and MSVS2012, Update 3; my project is classic ASP.NET web site which references other Class Library projects.

When I try to find implementation of interface methods using ReSharper (Ctrl+Shift+B) it displays me implementation in both the source code and compiled libraries.

I don't EVER need to see implementation in compiled library, but need that one that is in the source code.

**How to configure ReSharper to not search in compiled code? Or at least to not suggest it in search results.**

Thank you for advise!

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper will limit the scope of the found implementations depending on where the find command was invoked from. For example, if you put the text caret on a usage of `IDisposable` in your own code (a .cs file in your own solution), then ReSharper will only show implementations declared in your solution. If you first navigate to `IDisposable`, ReSharper will show a decompiled view of the interface. Invoking find implementations from this decompiled view will show all implementations, including those in referenced assemblies.

Comment: I don't use decompiled views at all.